# How to add Debian Universe in etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: debian, apt

In /etc/apt/sources.list

I added `universe` to

`deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free universe`

When I did `aptitude update` the log complained about:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/Release:
Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Should I care about the error?
Have I added Debian Universe correctly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's not Universe, universe, nor another permutation in Debian. This is a Ubuntu and derivatives only component. The only components you will find in debian are main, contrib and non-free. Only those.